# Multiple _ViewImports?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can I have multiple `_ViewImports.cshtml` files?  I don't want to import certain namespaces across **all** views but a certain **subset** of views.  My goal is to use **composition** to clearly understand who needs which imports.

Example:

```
+---Controllers  
|       OrdersController.cs  
|       ProductsController.cs  
|  
\---Views  
    |   _ViewImports.cshtml  //global using
    |  
    +---Orders  
    |       Index.cshtml  
    |       _ViewImports.cshtml  //using's specific to Orders
    |  
    \---Products  
            Index.cshtml  
            _ViewImports.cshtml  //using's specific to Products
```

In the above, any views under `Products` get the global `using`'s **+** the products `using`'s.  What I'm trying to achieve feels 'cleaner' .  This way I can tell who uses what.  Thoughts?

I don't see anything describing this scenario on the docs page: [Importing Shared Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#importing-shared-directives).  Maybe I missed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple `_ViewImports.cshtml`'s are supported and composition works as well but it doesn't cross the area boundary.

```
+---Areas  
|   \---Admin  
|       +---Controllers  
|       |       AdminController.cs  
|       |  
|       +---Models  
|       |       AdminModel.cs  
|       |  
|       \---Views  
|           |   _ViewImports.cshtml  
|           |  
|           \---Admin  
|                   Index.cshtml  //sees .\ViewImports.csthml
                                  //and \Areas\AdminViews\ViewImports.csthml
                                  //DOESN'T see \Views\ViewImports.csthml
|                   _ViewImports.cshtml  
|  
+---Controllers  
|       OrdersController.cs  
|       ProductsController.cs  
|  
\---Views  
    |   _ViewImports.cshtml  
    |  
    +---Orders  
    |       Index.cshtml  //sees .\ViewImports.csthml and \Views\ViewImports.csthml
    |       _ViewImports.cshtml  
    |  
    \---Products  
            Index.cshtml  //sees .\ViewImports.csthml and \Views\ViewImports.csthml
            _ViewImports.cshtml
```

[Demo Project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/Experiments/tree/master/Multiple%20_ViewImports%20QM)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple `_ViewImports.cshtml`, for example, under the regular `Views` folder, as well as under the `Views` folder in `Areas`.

[image]

They can of course import what you only need for the subset.

In my case, when a view from the area is rendered, it will look for the `_ViewStart.cshtml` and `_ViewImports.cshtml` defined for that area first. If not found, then it will go out to look for the general ones.

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Hi David - kinda.  Do the area imports get the global imports?  I've updated my question too.

Comment: @spottedmahn: No, in my OP I mentioned that MVC will first see if the area has a `_ViewImports.cshtml` defined or not. If yes, it won't look further.

Comment: FYI, [composition works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56706570/185123) but it doesn't cross areas apparently.